# Createjs create timer clock for game

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, easeljs, createjs

Does anyone know the best way to create a timer clock in Createjs please? I know I could do something in html and reference it with the DOMElement, but I have had a bit of a nightmare getting that to work in the past? Basically I need to show a timer in a container so the person playing my game can see how long it has taken them to complete a level - pretty standard stuff.

Even better still, if I could get it to use the font in my bitmap text that would be nice. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just track time in JS, and output it to a `BitmapText` element.

```
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

// in your update loop:
currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
var time = Math.floor((currentTime-startTime)/1000);
myBitmapText.text = time + "s";
```

Comment: Thanks GSkinner - and do you think it would be okay to use bitmaptext  (fontsheet) to render the time numbers?  I would like the time to match the font of all the other assets I have on the screen. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes. BitmapText doesn't care what text you provide it, so long as it has the appropriate characters defined in its font.

Comment: You're new to StackOverflow, so it might be worth taking a look at the SO Tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comments should be used to comment on or ask clarifying questions about the original topic. Create new questions when appropriate. Also, make sure to "accept" correct answers.